# Set Class on document ready, depending on field Value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where i need to add a class to a div, depending on a field value. The field value in this example is a Select input, however in the actual scenario, its a returned field on the page I am finding by document.getElementById.

The fiddle is here https://jsfiddle.net/s3w3ocy8/3/

Currently there is no change in the selected option/result change...

I have updated the code below (thanks Praveen and Alexander)

Any advice would be gratefully received!

Thanks

CSS:

```
<style>
.active{color:red;background-color:blue;}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<select id="select1">
<option>Select</option>
<option>Pill1</option>
<option>Pill2</option>
<option>Pill3</option>
</select>

<div id="pill1" class="pill1">
Pill 1
</div>
<div id="pill1Result">
result 1
</div>
<div id="pill2" class="pill2">
Pill 2
</div>
<div id="pill2Result">
result 2
</div>
<div id="pill3" class="pill3">
Pill 2
</div>
<div id="pill3Result">
result 3
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function($) {
var value = ('#select1');
switch ($(value).val()) {
    case "Pill1":
        $('#pill1,#pill1Result').addClass('active');
        break;
    case "Pill2":
        $('#pill2,#pill2Result').addClass('active');
        break;
    case "Pill3":
        $('#pill3,#pill3Result').addClass('active');
        break;
    default:
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: You've forgotten to ask a question explaining why it fails.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara It is clear. :) Yes, we need to understand by seeing the code.

Comment: Sorry guys, wrote question in a rush. Updated to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `$` everywhere. Replace your code with:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  var value = '#select1';
  if ($(value).val() == "Pill1")
    $('#pill1,#pill1Result').addClass('active');
  if ($(value).val() == "Pill2")
    $('#pill2,#pill2Result').addClass('active');
  if ($(value).val() == "Pill3")
    $('#pill3,#pill3Result').addClass('active');
  else
    $('#pill1,#pill2,#pill3,,#pill1Result,#pill2Result,#pill3Result').removeClass('active');
});
```

And an improved code would look like:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  var value = '#select1';
  switch ($(value).val()) {
    case "Pill1":
      $('#pill1,#pill1Result').addClass('active');
      break;
    case "Pill2":
      $('#pill2,#pill2Result').addClass('active');
      break;
    case "Pill3":
      $('#pill3,#pill3Result').addClass('active');
      break;
    default:
      $('.active').removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

**Updated Working Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var value = '#select1';
  $(value).change(function() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    switch ($(this).val()) {
      case "Pill1":
        $('#pill1,#pill1Result').addClass('active');
        break;
      case "Pill2":
        $('#pill2,#pill2Result').addClass('active');
        break;
      case "Pill3":
        $('#pill3,#pill3Result').addClass('active');
        break;
      default:
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1">
  <option>Select</option>
  <option>Pill1</option>
  <option>Pill2</option>
  <option>Pill3</option>
</select>

<div id="pill1" class="pill1">
  Pill 1
</div>
<div id="pill1Result">
  result 1
</div>
<div id="pill2" class="pill2">
  Pill 2
</div>
<div id="pill2Result">
  result 2
</div>
<div id="pill3" class="pill3">
  Pill 2
</div>
<div id="pill3Result">
  result 3
</div>
```

Comment: `var value = $('#select1');` then `$(value)` is redundant. Really, that if block should be a switch case block.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I guessed it, and now changed it.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Check?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Thanks... :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar thanks for your input! Unfortunately, it's not working in jsfiddle (please see top link). Any thoughts?

Comment: @TheMikeyBoosh Sorry, I forgot to bind the event listener to the `change` event of the `<select>` tag. I will do that now.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thats great! Thank you very much!